# How do I remove the selection border on a table view cell?

Tags: ios, swift

[image: screenshot]

As you can see, there's a border when selecting. I want to remove this border.
I've tried:

```
func tableView(tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
    let cell = roomsTableView.dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier("roomsCell", forIndexPath: indexPath) as! RoomTableViewCell
    cell.room = rooms[indexPath.row]
    cell.layer.borderWidth = 0.0
    cell.contentView.layer.borderWidth = 0.0
    cell.layoutMargins = UIEdgeInsetsZero
    return cell
}
```

That doesn't work.

`self.roomsTableView.separatorStyle = UITableViewCellSeparatorStyle.None` is already set.

**Clarification:** Look at the middle row. It's selected.  You see the border above and below the couple? That's what I want to remove.

Comment: which border are you talking about???

Comment: He meant the separators. I think?

Comment: @DHEERAJ  I've clarified my question

Comment: any solution to this?

Answer (score 2):

I'm going to assume you want to remove the separator from your TableView. You can do this with:

`tableView.seperatorStyle = UITableViewSeparatorStyle.None`

Comment: I've clarified my question, please check, thank you.

Answer (score 0):

What is the height of the `imageView` compared to the cell? If the `imageView` is smaller by 2 points, the cells background will show through on the top and bottom of the `imageView`.

Another thing to look at is subclassing `UITableViewCell` and handling the selection state accordingly.

Comment: I've already subclassed. The image view is same height as cell (the background doesn't show through in other rows as you can see)

Comment: Do you have a simple reproducer project I could tinker with? Or steps for me to create something similar?

Answer (score 0):

just for anyone having the same issue setting the

SelectionStyle = UITableViewCellSelectionStyle.None

of your UITableViewCell should do the trick. That will remove the selection border (not the separator) on the item.

Answer (score 0):

Select the tableView and go to the attribute selector in the storyboard file, Then do the followings according to image attached

[image]

make **Selection to no selection** and uncheck **the show selection on touch**

Answer (score 0):

You can prevent this behaviour by setting

```
selectionStyle = .none
```

On your cell `awakeFromNib()` method.